# Create "virtual" external display for VNC control?

Tags: macos, mac, vnc, external-display

I have an extra iMac G5 that I no longer use for compatibility & speed reasons, and saw that you can control an additional "virtual" display on an iPhone (such as iDisplay). Is there a piece of software out there that will add another "virtual" external display to my main Mac, so I can control that additional screen through VNC on my G5?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [Screen Recycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html)? It allows you to use another Mac as a secondary display. If I understand your question correctly, this seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't support 64-bit Mac OS X and is $30 (too much at the moment)

Comment: It supports it now, but I will mention that Screen Recycler has a buggy experience and causes quite a few kernel panics. Beware.